# How to concatenate multiple rows' fields in a sap hana table

Tags: sql, hana

I use SAP-HANA database. I have a simple 2 column table whose columns are id, name. The rows are these:

```
1 - tom
1 - harry
1 - jack
2 - larry
```

I would like to group the rows by the id, and concatenate the names into a field, and thus obtain this:

```
1 - tom, harry, jack
2 - larry
```

Can you please tell me how we can perform this operation in sap-hana? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using HANA with revision 70, you can try this:-

```
SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(Name, ',')  AS Names
FROM TAB
GROUP BY ID;
```

And for more info read this

[How to Concatenate Column Value from Multiple Rows into a Single Column?](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3294829)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Trying to find little snippets like this in the Hana documentation is very painful.

Comment: @Ankit I was looking for this information with coalesce kind of functions inside hana script reference but as it turned out, it was deep buried in aggregate functions! Thanks a lot for sharing this.

Comment: @arcynum. What you said is so true!