# Multiple rows ins single row with row delimiter

Tags: sql, hana

I have this table:

```
CID CNAME ADDRESS
------------------
100 ABC   ABCD
200 DEF   DSDFD
```

I need to export the data from this table to file in this single row. This is what I want..

```
100 ABC ABCD  200 DEF DSDFD
```

I am using SAP HANA database. I have tried multiple options but not able to produce the format I want. Appreciate your help!!

Thank you..

Comment: does hana support STUFF?

Comment: duplicate of this case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673458/how-to-concatenate-multiple-rows-fields-in-a-sap-hana-table

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No HANA doesn't support STUFF.