# SAP HANA SQL - Concatenate multiple result rows for a single column into a single row

Tags: sql, hana

I am pulling data and when I pull in the text field my results for the "distinct ID" are sometimes being duplicated when there are multiple results for that ID. Is there a way to concatenate the results into a single column/row rather than having them duplicated?

It looks like there are ways in other SQL platforms but I have not been able to find something that works in HANA.

**Example**

```sql
Select
     Distinct ID
From Table1
```

If I pull only Distinct ID I get the following:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

However when I pull the following:
**Example**

```sql
Select
     Distinct ID,Text
From Table1
```

I get something like

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dog |
| 2 | Cat |
| 2 | Dog |
| 3 | Fish |
| 4 | Bird |
| 4 | Horse |

I am trying to Concat the Text field when there is more than 1 row for each ID.

What I need the results to be (Having a "break" between results so that they are on separate lines would be even better but at least a "`,`" would work):

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dog |
| 2 | Cat,Dog |
| 3 | Fish |
| 4 | Bird,Horse |

Comment: using string_agg you can do this and link to show the answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673458/how-to-concatenate-multiple-rows-fields-in-a-sap-hana-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see Kiran has just referred to another valid answer in the comment, but in your example this would work.

```
SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(Text, ',')
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY ID;
```

You can replace the ',' with other characters, maybe a '\n' for a line break

I would caution against the approach to concatenate rows in this way, unless you know your data well.  There is no effective limit to the rows and length of the string that you will generate, but HANA will have a limit on string length, so consider that.

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate the help!